# Name for pattern of an object providing information about a held object

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a name for the pattern of instantiating an object holding another one and executing informative methods on the held object?

```golang
type Foo {
    prop1 string
    prop2 string
    prop3 bool
}

type Bar {
    foo Foo
}

func (b Bar) info1() bool {
    return b.foo.prop1 == f.foo.prop2
}

func (b Bar) info2() (string, string) {
    split1 := strings.Split(b.foo.prop1, "sep1")
    split2 := strings.Split(b.foo.prop2, "sep2")
    return strings.Join(split1, "newsep1"), strings.Join(split2, "newsep2")
}
```

Below a (stripped down) code snippet from a PR for carvel kapp I am working on which exhibits this pattern.

(Note: In the actual `kapp` code `VersionedResource` isn't used for informative purposes only, but that is a different issue.)

```golang
// Copyright 2020 VMware, Inc.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// ...

const (
    nameSuffixSep = "-ver-"
)

type VersionedResource struct {
    res                 ctlres.Resource
    stripNameHashSuffix bool
}

func (d VersionedResource) StripNameHashSuffix() bool {

    stripEnabled := d.stripNameHashSuffix

    // TODO should properly check using a ResourceMatcher
    matchesRequiredKind := d.res.Kind() == "ConfigMap" || d.res.Kind() == "Secret"

    return stripEnabled && matchesRequiredKind

}

// [...]

func (d VersionedResource) BaseNameAndVersion() (string, string) {
    name := d.res.Name()
    pieces := strings.Split(name, nameSuffixSep)
    if len(pieces) > 1 {
        return strings.Join(pieces[0:len(pieces)-1], nameSuffixSep), pieces[len(pieces)-1]
    }
    if d.StripNameHashSuffix() {
        pieces = strings.Split(name, "-")
        if len(pieces) > 1 {
            return strings.Join(pieces[0:len(pieces)-1], "-"), ""
        }
    }
    return name, ""
}

func (d VersionedResource) Version() int {
    _, ver := d.BaseNameAndVersion()
    if len(ver) == 0 {
        if d.StripNameHashSuffix() {
            return -1
        }
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Missing version in versioned resource '%s'", d.res.Description()))
    }

    verInt, err1 := strconv.Atoi(ver)
    if err1 != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Invalid version in versioned resource '%s'", d.res.Description()))
    }

    return verInt
}

func (d VersionedResource) UniqVersionedKey() ctlres.UniqueResourceKey {
    baseName, _ := d.BaseNameAndVersion()
    return ctlres.NewUniqueResourceKeyWithCustomName(d.res, baseName)
}

func (d VersionedResource) TrackVersions() bool {
    _, hasVersionedAnn := d.res.Annotations()[versionedResAnnKey]
    return hasVersionedAnn
}

func (d VersionedResource) IsVersioned() bool {
    if d.StripNameHashSuffix() {
        return true
    }
    return d.TrackVersions()
}

func (d VersionedResource) IsExistingVersioned() bool {

    // Expect that versioned resources should not be transient
    // (Annotations may have been copied from versioned resources
    // onto transient resources for non-versioning related purposes).
    notTransient := !d.res.Transient()

    // TODO check moved during refactoring, but not sure why it is required
    _, version := d.BaseNameAndVersion()
    hasVersion := version != ""

    versionUnnecessary := !d.TrackVersions()

    return d.IsVersioned() && notTransient && (hasVersion || versionUnnecessary)

}

// ...
```

This struct is used for example like this:

*Edit: removed confusing builder patter*

```golang
// Copyright 2020 VMware, Inc.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// ...

func (d ChangeSetWithVersionedRs) groupResources(rs []ctlres.Resource) map[string][]ctlres.Resource {
    result := map[string][]ctlres.Resource{}


    groupByFunc := func(res ctlres.Resource) string {
        versionedRes := VersionedResource{res, d.stripNameHashSuffix}
        if versionedRes.IsVersioned() {
            return versionedRes.UniqVersionedKey().String()
        }
        panic("Expected to find versioned annotation on resource")
    }


    for resKey, subRs := range (GroupResources{rs, groupByFunc}).Resources() {
        sort.Slice(subRs, func(i, j int) bool {
            return d.versionedResourceName(subRs[i]).Version() < d.versionedResourceName(subRs[j]).Version()
        })
        result[resKey] = subRs
    }


    return result
}

// ...
```

Comment: This would typically be a [Decorator Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator).

Comment: Studying your link I stumble over "the wrapper implements the same interface as the wrapped object"; this irritates me: my `Bar` / `VersionedResource` object does not share an interface with `Foo` / `Resource`.

Comment: @criztovyl Could you show, please, where an object instantiated and where are informative methods executed? Did you mean informative methods as `IsVersioned` and etc...?

Comment: @StepUp The last code snippet contains both, `versionedResourceName` instantiates the object and `groupResources` uses the `IsVersioned` and `UniqVersionedKey` in `groupByFunc`.

Comment: I say "typically" because the common pattern approach to creating something like a `VersionedResource` from a `Resource` via composition would be a Decorator. Since all of the GoF structural design patterns utilize composition, it's easy to fall into the trap of assuming every occurrence of composition must be a pattern. Quite the opposite: most occurrences of composition are just composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, this piece of code:

- is not using any pattern.
- it is some sort of [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)
- this code is auxiliary code which can be used in code where additional steps are required to create an object

I mean this code:

```
const (
    nameSuffixSep = "-ver-"
)

type VersionedResource struct {
    res                 ctlres.Resource
    stripNameHashSuffix bool
}

func (d VersionedResource) StripNameHashSuffix() bool {

    stripEnabled := d.stripNameHashSuffix

    // TODO should properly check using a ResourceMatcher
    matchesRequiredKind := d.res.Kind() == "ConfigMap" || d.res.Kind() == "Secret"

    return stripEnabled && matchesRequiredKind
}



func (d VersionedResource) BaseNameAndVersion() (string, string) {
    name := d.res.Name()
    pieces := strings.Split(name, nameSuffixSep)
    if len(pieces) > 1 {
        return strings.Join(pieces[0:len(pieces)-1], nameSuffixSep), pieces[len(pieces)-1]
    }
    if d.StripNameHashSuffix() {
        pieces = strings.Split(name, "-")
        if len(pieces) > 1 {
            return strings.Join(pieces[0:len(pieces)-1], "-"), ""
        }
    }
    return name, ""
}

func (d VersionedResource) Version() int {
    _, ver := d.BaseNameAndVersion()
    if len(ver) == 0 {
        if d.StripNameHashSuffix() {
            return -1
        }
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Missing version in versioned resource '%s'", d.res.Description()))
    }

    verInt, err1 := strconv.Atoi(ver)
    if err1 != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Invalid version in versioned resource '%s'", d.res.Description()))
    }

    return verInt
}

func (d VersionedResource) UniqVersionedKey() ctlres.UniqueResourceKey {
    baseName, _ := d.BaseNameAndVersion()
    return ctlres.NewUniqueResourceKeyWithCustomName(d.res, baseName)
}

func (d VersionedResource) TrackVersions() bool {
    _, hasVersionedAnn := d.res.Annotations()[versionedResAnnKey]
    return hasVersionedAnn
}
```

Comment: As you just added: "when additional steps are required"; my Bar / VersionedResource itself does not need additional steps once instantiated. The instantiation of Bar / VersionedResource is the builder pattern, but not the object itself.

Comment: @criztovyl however, parameters  `res ctlres.Resource` are sent to method before instantiation. So it is necessary to make additional steps to run this method.

Comment: It was me - you answer the wrong question. My question is not about the behavior of `versionedResourceName`.

Comment: `versionedResourceName` *does* exhibit the builder pattern, but in this case I could simply inline that into `groupResources` without changing what `VersionedResource` does.

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify that.

Comment: The pure function one sound like what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: I think the builder pattern part of the question is confusing, i'd consider removing it, given the code is not in the question anymore. I would like to wait if maybe another answer comes around, and after some time accept the best one  :)